# Flexbox aligning input type=file boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Puzzled how to neatly align the name of the input field, with the "Choose file" dialog & the previous uploads. Any tips?

Looking for a simple, elegant solution.

```css
.inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 3em;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: left;
}
label {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0.3em;
  border: thin solid black;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class=inputs>
  <label>Form 1
    <input type=file name=form24><a href=#>Previous upload 1</a>
  </label>

  <label>Form something else
    <input type=file name=form24><a href=#>Named upload</a>
  </label>

  <label>Form blah
    <input type=file name=form24><a href=#>Previous upload</a>
  </label>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 3em;
  /* align-items: left;           <-- "left" is not a valid value */
  /* justify-content: left;       <-- "left" is not a valid value */
}

label {
  display: flex;                  /* establish nested flex container */
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0.3em;
  border: thin solid black;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
}

label > * {
  flex: 1;                        /* distribute container space evenly among flex items */
}
```

```html
<div class=inputs>
  
  <label>
    <span>Form 1</span><!-- wrap text in a span so it can be targeted by CSS -->
    <input type=file name=form24>
    <a href=#>Previous upload 1</a>
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>Form something else</span>
    <input type=file name=form24>
    <a href=#>Named upload</a>
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>Form blah</span>
    <input type=file name=form24>
    <a href=#>Previous upload</a>
  </label>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, though I noticed that it can easily go outside the border, especially where there multiple previous uploads, e.g. https://hendry.jsbin.com/ganoru/

Comment: to fix your labels going outside the borders add, flex-wrap:wrap; in your label class and that will wrap everything in smaller resolutions/devices

Comment: @hendry, consider using the `flex-basis` property instead of `flex-grow` to set more stable widths for the flex items. With `flex-basis` you can ensure precise alignment among columns: https://jsbin.com/rujodevaki/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: To keep all content inside the borders you need to decide how to handle the overflow. You can use `overflow-x: auto`, `flex-wrap: wrap`, etc.

Comment: I think wrapping is fine, as long as each item is on it's own line. I don't like the look of `label > :nth-child(3) { flex: 1 0 40%; }` in https://jsbin.com/rujodevaki/1/edit?html,css,output